# Jquery If condition not working when appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<ul id="marketQuotes">
    <li class="main">
        <h4><span class="broker">Achuta Cashew Vengurla </span><span class="place">Vengurla </span><span class="time">25 Aug 10:54AM</span></h4>

        <ul class="submenuLevel1">
            <li class="subcomm">Kernels-Vengurla</li>
            <li class="level1">W180 - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 9000 to 9000 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">W210 - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 7600 to 7600 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">W240 - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 6600 to 6600 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">W320 - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 5700 to 5700 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">W400 - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 5100 to 5100 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">JH - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 5200 to 5200 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">K - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 4900 to 4900 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">LWP - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 4600 to 4600 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">S - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 5000 to 5000 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="main">
        <h4>Achuta Cashew Vengurla-Vengurla - 25 Aug 10:54AM</h4>

        <ul class="submenuLevel1">
            <li class="subcomm">Kernels-Vengurla</li>
            <li class="level1">S - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 5000 to 5000 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">LWP - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 4600 to 4600 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">K - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 4900 to 4900 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">JH - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 5200 to 5200 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">W400 - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 5100 to 5100 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">W320 - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 5700 to 5700 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">W240 - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 6600 to 6600 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">W210 - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 7600 to 7600 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
            <li class="level1">W180 - 10kg+VAT 5% :&nbsp;&nbsp;Rs. 9000 to 9000 (<span class="no-change">0</span>)</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

On click of a button initially appending `.main` li through ajax call. and then appending one more li to `ul` list and so on. I am using this script on button click to add spans for styling of `'h4`:

```
    $(function () {
        $('#marketQuotes .main').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find('span').length) {
                console.log('yes');
                // found!
            } else {
                console.log('no');
                $('.main h4').html(function () {
                    var txt = $(this).text();
                    var classes = ['broker', 'place', 'time'];
                    $(this).html($.map(txt.split(/-/), function (val) {
                        return $('<span/>', {
                            'class': classes.shift()
                        }).text(val)[0];
                    }));
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

However, when appending the second `li` the first `li`s `h4` tag should not change as it already has spans which is not getting done.

Am I doing something wrong here? **[JSBIN Link](http://jsbin.com/tuzuc/1/edit)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'else' is working, your function needs to look more like this:

[Working Bin](http://jsbin.com/canafaqicuvo/1/edit)

#### js

```
    $('.main h4').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('span').length) {
            console.log('yes');
            // found!
        } else {
            console.log('no');
           var classes = ['broker', 'place', 'time'];
          $(this).html($.map($(this).text().split(/-/), function (val) {
            return $('<span/>', {
              'class': classes.shift()
            }).text(val)[0];
          }));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `$('.main h4')` which targets all the `.main` elements in the document, instead of targeting only the current `.main` document targeted by the current loop. So try a context based search like `$(this).find('h4')`

```
$(function () {
    $('#marketQuotes .main').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('span').length) {
            console.log('yes');
            // found!
        } else {
            console.log('no');
            $(this).find('h4').html(function () {
                var txt = $(this).text();
                var classes = ['broker', 'place', 'time'];
                $(this).html($.map(txt.split(/-/), function (val) {
                    return $('<span/>', {
                        'class': classes.shift()
                    }).text(val)[0];
                }));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up. but that is not returning to `else` condition right? http://jsbin.com/tuzuc/1/edit see updated